# Program only works with Serial.begin

Tags: serial, atmega2560

My program only works when the following line is added:

```
Serial.begin(9600);
```

When this is disabled/removed the program no longer switches output state regular

I'm using an Arduino Mega 2560.

When the line is **added**:

- The output is switched ON or OFF regular around every 1sec.

When the line is **removed**:

- The output is switched after 1 sec (as expected) but then switched multiple times after around 3 sec.
- I tried with another Arduino Mega 2560: This time, the output is switched after 1sec (as expected) but then switched multiple times right after (and not after around 3 sec).

What could be the problem?

My code:

```
byte inputPin2 = 2;
byte inputPin3 = 3;
byte outputPin = 13;
boolean outputPin_HIGH = false;
volatile short angle = -18;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);      //<----------------------
  pinMode(hallSensorPin, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(inputPin2, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(inputPin3, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(inputPin2), ISR_addAngle, CHANGE);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(inputPin3), ISR_addAngle, CHANGE);
}

void ISR_addAngle() {
  angle = angle + 18;
}

void loop() {
  if (angle == 900) {
    if (outputPin_HIGH) {
      digitalWrite(outputPin, LOW);
      outputPin_HIGH = false;
    } else {
      digitalWrite(outputPin, HIGH);
      outputPin_HIGH = true;
    }
    angle = angle - 900;
  }
}
```

Comment: "When this is disabled/removed the program no longer works..." is not very informative. What, exactly, doesn't work? What were you expecting to happen? What happened instead?

Comment: When the line is disabled/removed the program no longer receives the regular interrupts and the output therefore no longer switches state.

When the line is added:
The output is set (switched ON and OFF) regular around every 1sec.

When the line is removed:
The output is set after 1sec (as expected) but then set multiple times after around 3 sec.

Comment: ... or I think that the interrupt works (I can see that a signal is sent to the interrupt pin), but as I can't serial.print a flag, I don't know if it really works...

Comment: The program works fine with it, but I want to remove it (it was only for debugging)

Comment: you can store the flag values in an array ... when you reach some desired number of values stored, then call a function to do serial.begin and print out the values

Comment: I'm guessing, but it sounds like the 'proper' operation depends on UART interrupts which go away without 'Serial.begin()'. Can you confirm your sensor is indeed signaling as you expect it to?

Comment: @JRobert The interrupt comes from a driver and not a sensor (A LED lights up when it sends a signal), and I'm sure that the signal is sent as usual. I ran the code with "Serial.begin(9600);" with no problem and right after again without, with errors. I therefore also don't think there should be a problem with the signal that triggers the interrupt.

Comment: @jsotola I will try that tomorrow. But I'm sure that I get the expected flags at the right time when "Serial.begin(9600);" is used. I rather want to debug this error without serial.

Comment: It looks like you're using a ATMega328P-based Arduino (UNO,  Nano, etc).  But, you should probably say what you're using and remove all doubt.

Comment: @timemage I'm using an Arduino Mega 2560. I tried with another Arduino Mega 2560: This time, the output is switched after 1sec (as expected) but then switched multiple times right after (and not after around 3 sec).

Comment: It works without "Serial.begin(9600)" when using an Arduino Micro Pro (ATmega32u4). Here, pin 0 and pin 1 are used as the inputs to the interrupts. Nothing else is changed in the code. Sadly is this not a solution to the problem...

Comment: "output is switched after 1 sec (as expected)" why is 1 second expected?

Comment: When adding "Serial.begin(9600)" the "1 sec" is around that time I normally expect the output to switch. Without, it is very different. Why should that line matter?!?